# Question over combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A t-shirt is being sold in 8 colors, 4 sizes, collared or tee, and long sleeve or short sleeve.

a. How many different shirts are being sold?

b. What if collared shirts only come in 5 colors and 2 sizes?

For a, it would simply be $8*4*2*2=128$ combinations right?

For b, it would be $5*4*2=40$ combinations right?

Comment: Your answer to (a) is correct.  Your answer to (b) forgets all the tee-shirts.

Comment: So it would be $40+8∗4∗2=104$ combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a) right. In b), you counted only the collared shirts, the second type should also be included.

Comment: Ah so it would be $40+8*4*2=104$ combinations